# Text gets highlighted when I press my mute button

Tags: html, css, selection, highlight, imagebutton

I have a mute button that toggles between two images (one for mute and one for unmute), and the button itself does as it's supposed to. But for whatever reason, when I press my button one too many times, or too fast, the closest elemenr (wether it be text or image) gets highlighted, as if the button is a transparent layer and I'm actually just pressing the background of my webpage. Why does my mute button do this? I've gone through my script multiple times, but can't adress the issue. Is there anything I can wrap my mute button into to make it behave more like a button?

this is the code for the button

```
<style>
.unmute{     
background-image: url(unmute.png);
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
margin-left: 25px;
width:153;
height:96;
cursor: pointer;
}

.mute{
background-image: url(mute.png);
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

<audio id="track" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="poopsyflop.wav"/>
</audio> 

<div class='unmute' onclick="document.getElementById('track').muted =
!document.getElementById('track').muted;$(this).toggleClass('mute')"></div>
<a href="#noscroll" id="mute"></a>
```

(I've unwrapped the Script jquery code, so it looks different (more messy) in my script)
Is there anything I can add/remove from my button codes to make it act more like a button?
(I will go further into details if necessary)

Thanks in advance to everyone!

-Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deactive user selection on elements with CSS:

```
.unmute,
.mute 
{
   -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
       -ms-user-select: none;
           user-select: none;
}
```

Browser compability: http://caniuse.com/#search=user-select

**EDIT:** You could also use a real button element and style it as you wish.

Comment: @DanielThorstensen please accept the answer of Doodlebunch

Comment: I just did. For some reason i had to wait 9 minutes until I could. Perhaps the answer needs to be there for x amount of time until it can be accepted